# Between clause doesn't work

Tags: mysql

Trying to set amount range like 0 to 9 10 to 19 ... 50 - 99 but when done individually i.e. a.Amount >50 returns data rows and similarly  a.Amount >100 returns data rows but the follwing returns null rows. Please help deadline is near! The Amount is a varchar data type.

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(a.TRANSACTION_DATE,'%d.%m.%Y')), '%Y%m') mnt, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT a.CUSTOMER_ID) totalNum
FROM    credittx a
WHERE   a.COUNTRY = 'Germany'
        AND a.AMOUNT   BETWEEN   100 AND 50
GROUP   BY DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(a.TRANSACTION_DATE,'%d.%m.%Y')),'%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 2):

The range is from-to

do `BETWEEN 50 AND 100`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment that **50 is less than 100** so please change:

`AND a.AMOUNT   BETWEEN   100 AND 50`

to:

```
AND a.AMOUNT BETWEEN 50 AND 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you must have between 50 AND 100. Not 100 AND 50.

```
SELECT   
DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(a.TRANSACTION_DATE,'%d.%m.%Y')), '%Y%m')   mnt, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a.CUSTOMER_ID) totalNum
FROM    credittx a
 WHERE   a.COUNTRY = 'Germany'
 AND         a.AMOUNT   BETWEEN   50 AND 100
 GROUP   BY DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(a.TRANSACTION_DATE,'%d.%m.%Y')),'%Y%m')
```